# Is possible to reinstall all npm packages to save-exact version?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

I have a lot packages with carat, eg.:

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
"node": "^16.3.1"
```

And i would like change it into exact versions:

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"node": "16.3.1"
```

I know i could change it by reinstalling it with -save-exact flag but i have many packages. Can it be automated?

Comment: How about a simple find and replace in your editor?

Comment: As i said i have a lot of packages and i would like to automate that :D

Comment: An alternative could be to use the "npm ci" command. Which is meant to be used in automated environments like your build pipeline. It will install the exact versions that are specified in your package-lock file https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci